# How to store a very large image on an iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, ios

What's the best way to store a very large image for an iOS app?  I want an app to be able to view images that might be hundreds of megabytes, perhaps as much as a gigabyte as jpeg. I need to be able to store the image and retrieve selected areas for display.

Currently the images are cut into 512x512 pixel tiles and stored as jpeg files in a directory tree with tens of thousands of tiles (actually an image pyramid including downsamples).

Ignoring the question of displaying the image, I'm interested in the most efficient, manageable way to store this data on the device: files, like they currently are, in an sqlite database or something else?

Second part to the question.  Is there a limit to the amount of data an app can store, or can an app keep importing data up to the storage limit of the device.  I'm asking here about data that an app imports after it's installed.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this is to pre tile the enormous image so the tiles can be quickly retrieved from the file system on an as needed basis. One problem with very large images is that most solutions require the whole image to be rendered into a context, consuming vast amounts of memory. On a system like iOS, where memory is limited, the way to solve this is to use a library like ***libjeg*** or ***libjpegturbo*** to render an image a line at a time, then save the pixels into a raw file. The downside to doing this directly is that when you need one tile, you need to jump all over the file system finding each row of a tile. Thus a better solution is to not only incrementally scan, but incrementally tile too. You can use mmap to map the file into just the area you need, so you can really minimize memory consumption. That said, you can thrash the Unified Buffer Queue on iOS so badly the app crashes, or even the whole system!

If you are curious about how to implement the above solution, there is a freely available project on github - [PhotoScrollerNetwork](https://github.com/dhoerl/PhotoScrollerNetwork) - that does all the above.

Comment: I would like to do exactly what PhotoScroller does. The only different is the tile image files(already pre-tiled) come from server. Is PhotoScrollerNetwork a good starting point for this?

Comment: No, if you have pretiled images you can just use PhotoScroller. That said, what you need to do is either download all 800 or so images before you attempt to show the image, or if you don't network delay will most certainly make the rendering slow and chunky. A good way to do it is download the lowest resolution image first - the smallest one - and just show that one until the other images are downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

A sample from Apple: [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: thx, but the question is about the best way to **store** a large image on an iOS device, not how to display.

Comment: That is the answer, look at how they are storing the very large images they use as samples.  Basically the images are broken out into tiles.

Comment: The sample has small images - I'm asking about images 2-3 orders of magnitude larger.  Are you saying I can just put a 1GB image tiled as 100k files in a single directory and there wont be any problems or performance issues?  Will that work ok and be free from performance issues when iTunes backs it up?

Comment: I am not sure the maximum number of files can be created in one directory. You can create more directories if needed.

Comment: @ohho sure you can create more directories.  Have you ever created an application with 10-100k files?  Are there any issues with this (esp performance)?  Is iTune ok with backing up a application with a large number of files?

Comment: what about storing the files on a web server?

Comment: @thompson I do not have experience of storing large number of files in my apps. However, you can test how iTunes performs by a 3rd party app. For example, you can add files to GoodReader and see how iTunes performs. In my personal experience, when there are too many files (or files size are huge) in the app's Documents folder, the sync will take forever (for example, when there are 20 GBs of PDF are added to GoodReader, iTunes does not finish sync after 10+ hours). As a side note, iTunes does not sync all folders (e.g. `tmp` folder is not sync'ed). If appreciable, you may use the tmp folder.

Comment: @ohho that's a useful data point - 10hrs is pretty bad. do you have an estimate of how many PDF's there were in your 20GB example?

Comment: @meronix good suggestion, but cellular data is too flakey for that to be an option

Comment: @thompson: "... as 100k files in a single directory and ..." <- but why you need to put all the files in the same folder? if your problem is just that... why don't you use subfolders?

Comment: @meronix I wasn't suggesting that - someone else suggested I should follow the PhotoScoller example, which does that. My question was trying to get advice from someone who had been down this path before as to the best way to proceed, so I don't end up with performance problems or hit limits on the device, or have 10 hr backups with iTunes etc.

Comment: @thompson, what did you end up doing?

Answer (score -1):

What about splitting into parts. Then it can be gathered by your application if needed

Comment: my question is what's the best way to do this on an iOS device?  100,000 100kb tiles stored as files in the file system, 1GB sqlite database with a 100,000 rows of blobs, or something else?  Currently we use files on a desktop computer - does that approach work ok on iOS?

Comment: Files are better than in a DB, the DB is more easily trashed.  You can keep a DB of indexes to which files you use for what though.

Comment: can't say i've ever had a problem with corrupted sqlite databases - is this a common issue with the iOS implementation?