# HUGE image to show on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Ok, here's my problem. I have a HUGE jpg file, 18000 x 18000 pixels 41MB in size.
If you really need to know, it's a map of a section of the country with services.

My project is really simple. I just need to be able to zoom and display this granddaddy size image. All the way from aspect fit to 100% on the iPhone. I'm not too sure if this can be done or how long it will take. Would appreciate any insights.

I have tried using imageView but I read that it really shouldnt exceed 1024 x 1024. That is way below what I have. If you have an idea how to go about doing this, please share!

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036943/how-to-store-a-very-large-image-on-an-iphone-ipad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036943/how-to-store-a-very-large-image-on-an-iphone-ipad)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should split the image into tiles, at a range of magnifications. Calculate and build these off-line, and ship them as individual files in the app bundle. Given the zoom in your display, pick the closest zoom size. You then select which tiles are needed to cover the screen, and make a grid of them. As the user zooms, select the appropriate tile size.

The benefit of this is that you don't ever have to load HUGE files into memory, only as much as needed.

This is how Google maps does it.

Can't give you any code, sorry!

Comment: Specifically, Google Maps uses the CATiledLayer layer class for its map view. That is what allows you to have a virtually huge image that loads piece by piece on demand.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow an approach similar to what Google Maps and other map sites do. You need to slice the whole map in sections, so the users don't need to load the whole map if it's not always necessary (plus makes loading time way faster)

There's a couple of solutions that might work for you like [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org/) or even creating a Custom Google Map with your images as seen [here](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/custommap.htm) and [here](http://mapki.com/wiki/Add_Your_Own_Custom_Map)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from Apple for processing large images called [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html).  The images have already been tiled.  If you need an example of tiling an image in Cocoa check out [cimgf.com](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/)

Comment: I would like to do what exactly PhotoScroller does but the pre-tiled image come from network not bundle. What I think is ,when `drawRect:rect` called, maybe I should start the fetching operation and save the rect. When fetching is finished, the called `setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect` to update the tile area. Is it really a good approach?